# RESTHeart issue with filters

Tags: java, mongodb

I've been using RESTHeart on top of mongodb to have crud support with Mongodb's REST interface. Its working fine when I'm not using any filter, however when I tried to apply filter with the HTTP GET request as provided in the [documentation](http://restheart.org/docs/walkthrough.html) I got error with the stacktrace as provided below.

Request: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/inBeta/donor?filter="{'name':'john'}"`

> 14:15:49.373 [XNIO-1 task-1] ERROR c.s.restheart.handlers.ErrorHandler
>   - error handling the request java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.bson.BSONObject
>           at com.softinstigate.restheart.db.CollectionDAO.lambda$getCollectionData$45(CollectionDAO.java:178)
>   ~[restheart.jar:0.9.7]
>           at com.softinstigate.restheart.db.CollectionDAO$$Lambda$20/1288164368.accept(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]
>           at java.util.ArrayDeque$DeqSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source)~[na:1.8.0_31]
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
>           at com.softinstigate.restheart.db.CollectionDAO.getCollectionData(CollectionDAO.java:177)
>   ~[restheart.jar:0.9.7]

When I didn't apply any filter its returning JSON object, however with filters its returning BSON object which RESTHeart is unable to convert as JSON response. Will appreciate any help or direction to look into the issue.

P.S. There is no tag for [RESTHeart](http://restheart.org/), so it would be helpful if someone could create a tag for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, issue resolved :)

I tried using other APIs provided in documentation and found that everything is working except filter and hence trying out the request using the below request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/inBeta/donor?filter=%7B'username':'john'%7D
```

it worked. Hence the culprit is **double quotes** around filter query.