# how to use $in in MongoDB using Rest API

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I am using mongodb REST API to access data from a Java class and parsing it using JSON classes( `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` ). The code to access data is:

```
private String callWebService(String accountNumber) {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(
            "http://localhost:28017/mongoGCDB/HandlingInstruction/");
    url.append("?filter_NtwAccNo=").append(accountNumber);

    return findHandlingInstructions(url.toString());
}

private String findHandlingInstructions(String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String returnVal = "";
    try {

        JSONArray jArray = readJsonFromUrl(url).getJSONArray("rows");

        if (jArray.length() > 0) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            returnVal = json.getString("Dsc");

        } else {
            System.out.println("length =" + jArray.length());


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("*JSON WebService : "
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
            + " milliseconds *");

    return returnVal;
}

public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException,
        JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        return json;
    } finally {
        if(is != null)
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Currently I am able to access data for a single accountNo. But my need is to access data for multiple account numbers in a single call. I learned that using `$in` operator we can achieve it. So I tried to put different combinations ( `.../?filter_NtwAccNo={$in:[304006009,988211139]}` ) in the URL but didn't succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

With RESTHeart you do that with the following query parameter

filter={"NtwAccNo":{"$in":[304006009,988211139]}}

You can also limit the result set (pagination) using the query parameters page and pagesize.

Note that you might need to percent encode the url string (better if you use the URI class to build the url)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming used restheart ,

In restheart unit tests, examine [testGetUriWithFilterMany](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/blob/develop/src/test/java/org/restheart/test/unit/URLUtilisTest.java#L128)

```
/dbName/collName?filter={'_id':{'$in':[1,20.0,\'id\']}}
```

It seems you missed field name,
`{'accountNo':{'$in':[304006009,988211139]}}` it might look like that.

If still you get errors , try to encode your query.

```
{'accountNo':{'$in':[304006009,988211139]}} 
%7B'accountNo':%7B'$in':%5B304006009,988211139%5D%7D%7D
```

In [restheart api](http://restheart.org/docs/walkthrough.html), it seems hrefs come as encoded.

Comment: Thanks ilker for providing link and your suggestion. I tried as you said . modified code : encodedUrl.append("....").append("/?filter=").append(URLEncoder.encode("{'AcctNo':{'$in':[304006009,988211139]}}", "UTF-8"));  its returning 1000 rows.  I copied the query part and executed in Mongo VUE there its working fine. where am I going wrong.

Comment: Is it returning from rest service or you just queried on mongodb console?

Comment: The 1000 rows are being returned from rest service .  when I executed the same query {'AccNo':{'$in':[304006009,988211139]}} in MongoVUE query window it is working fine, and the shell window shows the command db.HandlingInstruction.find({'AccNo':{'$in':[304006009,988211139]}}); as executed and returns 2 documents.

Comment: Shaik, in filter parameter did you tried to remove double quotes? in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274954/restheart-issue-with-filters this post a user found an issue about it.

Comment: updated my question, added the complete code and I am not using rest heart API. Please provide your suggestions.